# Installing Google Cloud SDK in a container in non-interactive mode

Tags: docker, sdk, cloud, containers

Im trying to install the Google Cloud SDK in a container, but I need the prompts to automatically be answered yes.

I'm using this command "curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash"

It required answering yes/no, but i need it to automatically answer yes as this will be installed automatically from a container image.

How can I do this?

Comment: did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658740/gcloud-how-to-automate-installation-of-gcloud-on-a-server ?

Comment: I looked at that and executed a "export CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1" and it worked for answering prompts. Now it throws Source [/root/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc] in your profile to enable shell command completion for gcloud.
==> Source [/root/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc] in your profile to add the Google Cloud SDK command line tools to your $PATH.